# Drupal 8 how to create a template for a custom block type

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-theming, drupal-blocks, custom-code

I want to create a template for a custom block type I've created by going to structure/block layout/ types/ add custom block type. The type I've created is called menu. How do i create a template for this custom block type from here? I'm not as familiar with Drupal so any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, add theme suggestion to your theme, paste it into yourthemename.theme file

```
function yourthemename_theme_suggestions_block_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables)
{
  // Block suggestions for custom block bundles.
  if (isset($variables['elements']['content']['#block_content'])) {
    array_splice($suggestions, 1, 0, 'block__bundle__' . $variables['elements']['content']['#block_content']->bundle());
  }
}
```

Now you can use theme suggestion per block bundle, copy block.html.twig to your theme and rename it to: block--bundle--your-block-type.html.twig

Comment: As well as make sure you enable twig.debug in development.services.yml to ese a print of which twig template the page is using for that block. ( See https://www.drupal.org/node/2598914 )